# What does a2ensite do apart from creating a symlink?

Tags: apache, perl, configuration

I regularly use `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` to enable and disable sites in Apache. As far as I know it does little more than simply creating a symlink from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. I can also do it manually, but because it saves me typing a few characters I use these shortcuts.

I just did a `cat /usr/sbin/a2ensite`, and to my surprise it's quite an elaborate program. According to the [man pages](http://man.he.net/man8/a2ensite), it does little more than enabling sites though. I briefly looked over the (Perl) source code, but even though it's a lot of code I don't really understand what it does more than simply creating a symlink.

Why does it need so much code to simply create a symlink? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually

- `a2enconf`
- `a2disconf`
- `a2dismod`
- `a2ensite`
- `a2dissite`

are all only symlinks to `a2enmod`:

```
$ /usr/sbin$ ll -d a2*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 15 17:33 a2disconf -> a2enmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 15 17:33 a2dismod -> a2enmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 15 17:33 a2dissite -> a2enmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 15 17:33 a2enconf -> a2enmod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   15424 Apr  5  2016 a2enmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 15 17:33 a2ensite -> a2enmod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    9870 Jul 15 17:33 a2query
```

and `a2enmod` implements the functionality of all six of them in one script.
It decides what to do depending on `$0` (i.e. the name the script was called with).

That's probably the reason why it's more complicated than a simple `ln -s`.

Comment: with the risk of being pedantic, and what does a2enmod do? I have installed slackware and it didn't come with this, so sometimes I need to follow how-to's for other distros and they cite this command. If I could do it manually, I can use such diverse how-to's better. Thanks